# How can I let a fragment know that the ArrayList was updated

Tags: android

So I have an ArrayList of a custom object and an adapter to show the contents through a ListView. You can click on separate objects in the ListView and a little animation expands and shows some extra informations. This behaviour is defined in the ArrayAdapter (because the animations didn't work how I wanted it to when used directly in createView().

Now if you click on a small image (X- to delete) of a listview element, an alertdialog pops up asking you if you're sure you want to delete that item. If you click Yes it removes it from the arraylist but notifyDataSetChanged(); doesn't refresh the adapter and onResume or something similar is never called because I never hid the fragment, just had an alert over it.

this is a rough code, part of my ArrayAdapter:

```
    deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        ArrayList<Book> XYZ = sharedFunctions.loadSortedArrayList(getContext());
                        XYZ.remove(position);
                        sharedFunctions.saveArrayList(context, XYZ);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("BLABLA").setNegativeButton("Cancel", dialogClickListener).setPositiveButton("Confirm", dialogClickListener).show();
    }
});
```

So how can I tell the Fragment (which is a tab) that the data has changed?

EDIT:
So I think the answers below were technically correct but I figured out that I was simply doing this all wrong. I removed the item from the ArrayList (which was loaded/saved in SharedPreferences) instead of removing it from the ArrayList that was used to construct the adapter. Stupid mistake tbh. Once I removed it from there as well, notifyDataSetChanged() worked. Thanks to you both for trying to help.-- (pretty new here so I'm not sure if i should delete the question but I'll just keep it like this for now).

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your fragment through the fragment manager. Here is an example how to do so:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("theTagThatFragmentSavedInFragmentManagerWith");
if (fragment != null) fragment.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition);
```

Comment: I have 4 tabs in this MainActivity, and use a ViewPagerAdapter (which uses FragmentManager through getSupportFragmentManager and for your suggestion, it can't resolve getChildFragmentManager().

Comment: That's alright, I thought you were on a fragment since you didn't mention. You can use `gerSupportFragmentManager()` with the fragment tag you assigned to your fragment in your `ViewPagerAdapter`.

Comment: I've managed to do so with ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager()... but now notifyItemChanged cannot be resolved. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to declare a function on your fragment named `notifyItemChanged` and notify your list adapter about the changed item in it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can also use localbroadcastreciever too. define  and register local braodcast in that fragment which you want to refresh and call that broadcast from adapter delete positive click. in broadcast onRecieve just check your adapter is not null and do like this

```
youradapterobject.notifyDataSetChanged();
```